# Selecting using random pairs of data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large file with three columns. The first two are integers and the third is a string.  I read it in using pandas  using

```
data = pd.read_csv("edges+stuff.txt", sep=' ', header=None, dtype={0:np.uint32, 1:np.uint32, 2:np.str})
```

Here is some example fake data:

```
2 0 Somestuff9
2 0 Somestuff0
1 1 Somestuff5
0 0 Somestuff7
2 0 Somestuff9
2 0 Somestuff5
2 1 Somestuff2
1 1 Somestuff8
1 1 Somestuff2
1 0 Somestuff4
2 1 Somestuff3
0 2 Somestuff9
1 1 Somestuff10
1 0 Somestuff9
```

I would like to perform the following random sampling which I am stuck on. I want to pick a number of random pairs that exist from the data frame. I don't want to pick a random row as, for example "1 1" occurs four times but I would like to have an equal chance of picking any pair that exists in the data frame. If I did pick "1 1" I would then like to output all the rows that start "1 1".

Using my example fake data, I would like to select some pairs randomly from [(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,2), (2,0), (2,1)] (these are all the pairs that exist in the data) and then use those pairs to select rows from the dataframe.

One way to do this would be to take the first two columns, sort them and perform the equivalent of `np.unique`. Then select random pairs from this uniqued list and then use them to select from the original dataframe.

> Is there some way to do this efficiently in pandas?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it perform too slowly for you?

Comment: @WayneWerner I am not sure how to perform the steps I described. How do you make a list of the unique pairs of the first two columns for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
df.head()
Out: 
   col1  col2        col3
0     2     0  Somestuff9
1     2     0  Somestuff0
2     1     1  Somestuff5
3     0     0  Somestuff7
4     2     0  Somestuff9
```

Select one pair randomly:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']].drop_duplicates().sample(n=1)
Out: 
   col1  col2
0     2     1
```

(Here drop duplicates drops all rows that have the same col1 col2 pairs except for the first one and `.sample(n=1)` select one among them.)

All rows that have `col1=2`, `col2=1`:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']].drop_duplicates().sample(n=1).merge(df)
Out: 
   col1  col2        col3
0     2     1  Somestuff2
1     2     1  Somestuff3
```

Comment: You can change the parameter of the `sample()` method from 1 to 10 (`.sample(n=10)`). It will select 10 unique pairs (assuming there are at least 10 unique pairs of course).

Comment: It's really a great and surprising answer! Pandas seems pretty amazing.

Comment: @eleanora Yeah, pandas is great. :)

Comment: OK so I see the performance problem now. Let me accept this answer and ask another one.